# Select column value only if match condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a table with s1 and s2 columns.

My query is:

```
SELECT s1, s2 
FROM myTable 
WHERE s1 = 1 OR s2 = 1
```

With sample data:

```
s1 s2
------
1  2
2  1
1  1
```

I want to get:

```
s1    s2
--------
1   NULL
NULL   1
1      1
```

Do you know a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN s1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS s1,
  CASE WHEN s2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS s2
FROM myTable
WHERE s1 = 1 OR s2 = 1
```